# Hex Code display size issue in mobile

Tags: css, html

I am using `&#x2715;` on my close button. In my chrome pc it displays the size that I wanted (`font-size:20px`) see the image below

[image]

However in my mobile I also use chrome but the size is smaller even they are the same page and I also check the view in desktop site but still the size is small see the image below

[image]

Js fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/reginaldt/cag7870j/
codepen link: http://codepen.io/reginaldt/pen/yaJqyo

Any reason for this? Thanks.

UPDATE: I used samsung galaxy core prime on the mobile view to replicate the problem. But when I used samsung galaxy s6, it display the size properly.

Comment: Are there any media queries affecting the size on smaller screens?

Comment: @ovokuro yes but I this http://mattkersley.com/responsive/ all of the sizes display normal except in mobile.

Comment: @ovokuro I provided jsfiddle and codepen links for examples

Comment: Your default font is different in Chrome Desktop and Chrome Mobile. The X is small when viewed with Firefox at Desktop.